# Gitlab update from source to packaged version

Tags: mysql, postgresql, gitlab, updates

I would like to update my Gitlab from version 8.12.7 ( installed from sources / MySQL version) to 9.X ( package version with PostgreSQL )

To do it, I installed a Gitlab-ce on the same version with PostgreSQL , did my backup as recommenced on the documentation, run the converter as recommended [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/mysql_to_postgresql.md#converting-a-gitlab-backup-file-from-mysql-to-postgres)

Then , I transfer the converted backup tar through SCP to the new server with packaged installation , but , when I run the

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore

I've got the following errors :
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: rmtlseek not stopped at a record boundary
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Like if my tar was corrupt , but I can successfully unpack it on both servers after the convertion step. I saw rsync could cause a problem but md5sum are the same on both side...

Any help would be gladely appreciated !
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found an answer

I've followed this [post](http://theterminallife.com/migrating-gitlab-to-gitlab-omnibus/)

There are some differences with the official  [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update/README.md#upgrading-from-a-non-omnibus-installation-to-an-omnibus-installation) that allowed me to fix my problems. Hope this can help some others...

Comment: One difference I notice before doing the restore is the `gitlab-ctl stop unicorn` (vs doing `gitlab-ctl stop puma`) in more recent backup/restore instructions. What is the reason for the difference here? What is this doing?